# How to get the values of ajax post in iis7.5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iis-7.5

Good day to all..

I have a problem.. I can't get the values that are send in my ajax code..

This is my ajax code

```
$(function(){
    $('#login').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var user = $('#username').val();
        var pass = $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'confirm_login.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{user:user, pass: pass},
            success : function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

this is my php code

```
<?php 
      echo "outside";
   if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
      echo "inside";
   }
?>
```

When I tried it, the result is outside..

I also tried to remove the echo "outside" but the result is empty..

So I can assume the problem is in the $_POST.. If you guys have encountered and resolved this pls help..

**Note:** This is in the iis7.5.

Answer (score 0):

I've already resolve it.. When I was looking in the networks tab in the chrome dev tools, I saw that it send a request to `confirm_login.php` and `confirm_login`..

I also remember I have a `rewrite` rule in my web.config that removes the `.php` in the url..  So what I did was just simply remove the `.php` in the url of the ajax and it works like a charm..

Just this `url:'confirm_login',`